# Как можно упростить данный алгоритм сортировки двух списков?

Tags: python

Как можно упростить данный алгоритм сортировки двух списков?

```
import itertools
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
print('Списки "a" и "b"')
print(a, b)
print('Объеденение списков "a" и "b"')
a.extend(b)
print(a)
print('Объеденённый список сортируем по возрастанию')
a.sort()
print(a)
lastlist = set(a[0] for a in itertools.groupby(a))
print('Удаляем повторяющиеся чилса из списка')
print(lastlist)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменил порядок:

- Сначала убираем дубликаты объединенного списка: `set(a + b)`
- После сортируем

Пример:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
print('Списки "a" и "b"')
print(a, b)
print('Объединение списков "a" и "b"')
lastlist = sorted(set(a + b))
print('Удаляем повторяющиеся числа из списка')
print(lastlist)
```

Comment: Именно такой код мне и нужен был, но до этого как только я не пробовал, постоянно выдавало ошибки

Comment: @Edward, раз ошибки были, могли и проблемный код поместить в вопрос, заодно узнали бы в чем ошибка была :)

Comment: В следующий раз так и сделаю, я первый раз задаю вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
print(sorted(set(a) | set(b)))
```

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]`